# Photoshop CC not responding when opening a 2MB PDF file

Tags: macos, finder, pdf, adobe-photoshop

There's a Mac on my job that recently got installed Adobe CC. I, myself, haven't used CC before, always CS6 so I don't know about the common errors, bugs, crashes or fixes. Moreover, I'm not a designer, I'm just the IT guy (I have only used CS6 for really basic stuff).

I've gone through the basic check, which included updating from Mavericks to Yosemite, and check adobe updates but the issue still persists.

The problem seems to happen by doing the following:

1. Open Finder and navigate to a folder with 2MB PDF files.
2. Drag one of those 2MB PDF files and drop it on the Photoshop icon located in the Dock
3. It may stop responding here, or when opening the `Crop To` dropdown box.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using PhotoShop CC 2014 under Yosemite on a 2012 MacBook Pro. I'm not seeing an issue, even testing with a 5MB PDF.

One thing to consider is that the PDF file is corrupt. To check this, try loading some alternative PDFs into PhotoShop.

Instead of drag-dropping the PDF onto the Dock icon, you can also try either of the following:

1. Right-click the PDF, then choose **Open with** >> **PhotoShop**.
2. With PhotoShop open, drag-drop the PDF from the Finder window to the PhotoShop window.

Comment: I tried opening the PDF with Chrome and the PDF was unable to load. Tried with Adobe Acrobat and the computer Froze (had to hard-reboot), tried just selecting the PDF file to see the content in the preview and it also froze. The PDF is corrupt indeed. But, why would the computer crash on a corrupted file?

Comment: Well, the quality of a given PDF can vary wildly, depending upon the arrangement of graphic objects within the original graphic design application, and the software tool used to generate the PDF. There are many "free" PDF creators available, as opposed to using a full-blown Adobe Acrobat, and the issue is that (under the cover), the PDF code generated by "free" PDF generators can be questionable. Of course, most people just use the PDF to (say) send a quick proof to a customer, and such issues don't appear under visual inspection.